# spark streaming accessing azure blob

Tags: azure, hadoop, apache-spark, hdfs, spark-streaming

Im trying to register my azure blob storage to my spark streaming but get this code & error:-

Code:-

```
SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("JavaNetworkWordCount");
        JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sparkConf, Durations.seconds(1));
        ssc.textFileStream("wasb[s]://mycontainer@rtest.blob.core.windows.net/");
        ssc.start();
        ssc.awaitTermination();
```

Not sure what should be in the path of WASB link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hdinsight-hadoop-use-blob-storage#address-files-in-azure-storage

The link says I should give a path but my container does not have any path. The images are directly stored in the container.

Error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: No output operations registered, so nothing to execute
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:224)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.DStreamGraph.validate(DStreamGraph.scala:163)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.validate(StreamingContext.scala:513)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.liftedTree1$1(StreamingContext.scala:573)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext.start(StreamingContext.scala:572)
    at org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext.start(JavaStreamingContext.scala:554)
    at org.bnr.process_panos.JavaNetworkWordCount.main(JavaNetworkWordCount.java:43)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:736)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:210)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative path or an absolute path. For example, the hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar file that comes with HDInsight clusters can be referred to by using one of the following:

**Example1**: wasb://mycontainer@myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/example/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar

**Example2:** wasb:///example/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar

**Example3**: /example/jars/hadoop-mapreduce-examples.jar

The following error message occurs without output operator on DStream no computation is invoked. You will need to invoke any of below method on stream.

**print()**

**foreachRDD(func)**

**saveAsObjectFiles(prefix, [suffix])**

**saveAsTextFiles(prefix, [suffix])**

**saveAsHadoopFiles(prefix, [suffix])**

For more details, refer “http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#output-operations”.

Comment: I can use only inside hdinsight  cluster or can I use the storage link outside of insight cluster?